# How can I assign user defined sml datatypes to have a integer (as string) datatype?

Tags: types, interpreter, sml

Very new to sml. My problem is that I'm trying to make my own datatype, but I can not use ints in the naming convention of the items that are appart of the datatype

```
datatype psu = 350w | 450w | 550w | ... etc;
```

error thrown:

```
stdIn:16.15-16.30 Error: syntax error: deleting  STRING BAR STRING
```

Is there some way I can convert these numbers into a string that would be acceptable for the sml interpreter? I really don't want to name my variable "three hundred and fifty watts" or anything.

I tried looking up a toString and just making the variables explicitly strings, but I could not find a helpful toString and making the variables strings just threw another error

Comment: An identifier can't begin with a digit. What's wrong with `datatype psu = W350 | W450 | W550 | ...`, or `datatype psu = Watts of int`? What does this type represent and how are you going to use it?

Comment: BTW: that definition does not produce that error. Your actual definition said `datatype psu = "350w" | "450w" | ...`. I think you've been so focused on strings that you're becoming stuck in them as a solution, but they rarely are.

Comment: Even I was about to suggest this..`datatype psu = W350 | W450 | W550 | ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, identifiers in SML (as in many other programming languages) cannot begin with digits.

```
datatype psu = W350 | W450 | W550 | ...
```

This would work.

Something like the following would also work, *but* does not let you constrain the possibilities.

```
datatype psu = Watts of int
```

Similarly, if you represent that value as a string like `"350W"` you cannot ensure at compile-time that the value held in that string is in a particular set of options.

Comment: I did not realize that identifiers in sml could not start with digits. I guess I will use the W350 style for my program. Thank you!